# Select Line from listbox and then convert to string

Tags: vb.net, string, listbox

I want to search for a small bit of text in my listbox, if it's in the listbox I want to select it, and then covert it to a string.

How do I do this?

Because I cannot find the good command to select something on a specific line!

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code that you have tried and explain where it fails?

Answer (score 1):

To select a ListBox item, set the ListBox's `SelectedIndex` property. So, for example:

```
Dim stringToFind As String = "someString"

For i As Integer = 0 To Me.MyListBox.Items.Count - 1
    Dim itemAsString As String = Me.MyListBox.Items(i).ToString()
    If itemAsString.Contains(stringToFind) Then
        Me.MyLabel.Text = itemAsString
        Me.MyListBox.SelectedIndex = i
        Exit For 'If you're using a MultiSelect ListBox, you can add to Me.MyListBox.SelectedIndices and remove this line.
    End If
Next
```

Comment: It works perfectly, but then how do I copy it to another label?

Comment: @user1054822: Just assign `itemAsString` to your label's `Text` property. I've edited my answer to include that.